# apache2 -l show itk.c, this mean prefork or worker?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Well i'm trying to check if my apache2 is running on prefork or worker,

apache2 -l show:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  itk.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

itk.c means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. Your Apache2 has been compiled with the nonstandard [apache2-mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) patch. It's similar to prefork, but not the same.

Comment: well if i edit apache2.conf in <IfModule mpm_prefork_module> properties, it will make effect?